# Creating a glitch effect similar to Watch Dogs

Tags: opengl, libgdx, shaders, graphic-effects

I'm currently working on a LibGDX game. When a user does something wrong, I would like all the graphics on the screen to jitter very similar to the glitch/distort effect seen in the game Watch Dogs (See Below).

My question is this: can this effect be achieved in real time by writing a shader? If so are there any references online on how to do this? (I've had a quick Google but all I could find is how to achieve this effect in Photoshop/After Effects).

Thank you for your help.

Screen jitter: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EYkqC9uI8Nc

Text glitch effect: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Wj26Wp2AH-U

[image]

Comment: It most probably can be achieved by rendering the image to a texture and then bending your brain to come up with the shader processing pipeline to achieve it. The real question is: what would you use it for? It looks more in the lines of a demo-scene project than a skill a game programmer should have. Of course, doesn't hurt to try it. An educated guess tells me that WD achieved that by playing Flash movies instead of using sophisticated shaders as you intend to. So, if a AAA doesn't do it, why would you?

Comment: @teodron "The real question is: what would you use it for?" I think the answer to this "real" question can be found in the original question. "a skill a game programmer should have" not everyone limits themselves to skills they "should" have. "So, if a AAA doesn't do it, why would you?" In many ways, this way of thinking slows down progress.

In conclusion, the only relevant information your comment brings is "bending your brain to come up with the shader processing pipeline to achieve it" which is no information at all.

Comment: Of course the effect can be achieved in realtime. Texture offset maps + overlays, possibly in multiple layers and/or animated. It's all quite trivial, apart from the art asset creation process, which might take some time.

Comment: @rootlocus well, my bad, I didn't read the whole question carefully , sorry :(. Yet, it's quite difficult to accomplish the whole range of WD glitches the user may be after. Nevertheless, asking questions is the key to progress. Even bad questions need to be answered - since the OP is making a game, this effect pipeline alone could be a task for a month or so working full-time on it. Cheers!

Comment: It seems the "effect" they used in this specific image is randomly pick thin vertical rectangles and flip (invert) the colors in this rectangles which should be rather simple to accomplish.

Comment: I think the question is too broad at this point. There are many examples for a "glitch" effect, two of which in the links the asker provides and each implemented completely differently. What are your precise requirements? You need to know what you wish to do before you set out to do it or the answers you'll get in this case are write a shader.

Comment: @Zehelvion this is actually a really simple solution you've came up with. So I would essentially place lots of random thin rectangles on top of my texture and flip/invert the colours whilst adding a small amount of random grey rectangles behind the text yeah? Probably a lot of trial and error involved to get this effect looking right but it could work :)

Comment: @Zehelvion also apologies for the not so precise requirements, I realised the videos and the image provided are quite different in effects. For the purpose of this question a shader that would produce a similar effect to the Watch Dogs image provided would be great (rectangular cut outs through the text with extra rectangular noise surrounding it).

Comment: @Zehelvion As an after thought, rather than calculating lots of random rectangles every time I need the screen to glitch, could I just create a simple black texture the same size as the screen and draw lots of white rectangles on top, then use it as a kind of mask? Then in the fragment shader I would just check the colour of the mask at that particular point and if its white, invert the colour?

Comment: @Rhakiras That is one "glitchy" behavior you could play with, another I would suggest to try, is to randomize rectangles and flip them, in one or both axes. A third option I saw there, was splitting the image to three color layers (RGB) and shifting each randomly. One last suggestion is making random characters appear for a split second on top of the legible text.

Comment: Rectangle select and then offset it. Basically grab sections of the image and move them. You also want to "cut" the region, so you copy and paint the region where it was to black or whatever.

Answer (score 6):

Creating the glitchy look can be accomplished in a broad spectrum of ways. In essence, what we have been culturally accustomed to accept as a glitch is everything that is a sudden distortion of what would otherwise be coherent content. Some glitches fit well with analogue transmission (i.e white noise) and others fit well with digital displays, random ascii symbols, flickering text, artifacts (like the negative rectangles). Throwing the three layers of color out of focus (is called bleeding and) is more reminiscent of CRT displays. You can also add some high amplitude vertical waves temporarily.

To make random ascii characters appear:

1. You can copy the original text string and rapidly randomly modify some of the characters.
2. You can use a spritesheet like [this](http://www.bay12forums.com/smf/index.php?topic=138672.0) and simply use randomly place sprites of characters, removing them shortly after that to make them flicker on the screen in an unpredictable manner.
3. To do the negative image thing, what you suggested would work. It is essentially a XOR between the text and the noise rectangles (if white is true and black is false).

Comment: Like you said tweaking is key here because it is an artistic effect and does not fall in a "working" / "not working" category.